# What is the mutual variation of $B^n(t)$ and $B^m(t)$?

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $(B(t))$ be a standard Brownian motion.

I know that by defintion $[B^n,B^m]_t$ is the mutual variation of $(B^n(t))$ and $(B^m(t))$ if for any sequence of partitions $(\Delta_n)$ with $|\Delta_n| \to 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{k=1}^n \big( B^n(t_k) - B^n(t_{k-1}) \big) \big( B^m(t_k) - B^m(t_{k-1}) \big) \to [B^n,B^m]_t.
\end{align*}
in probability.

I think this question should be asked frequently (there might even be a diplicate somewhere), yet I couldn't find an answer anywhere or calculate it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Ito's formula,
$$
B_t^n = n\int_0^t B^{n-1}_s\,dB_s+{n\choose 2}\int_0^t B_s^{n-2}\,ds,
$$
and likewise for $B^m_t$. The covariation of $B^n$ with $B^m$ is therefore
$$
mn\int_0^t B_s^{m+n-2}\,ds.
$$

Comment: Thanks for tha answer. By the way, you have written covariation insted of mutual variation. (The answer is for mutual variation, though)